# How to set increment counter in TextWatcher in getView method?

Tags: android

I'm trying to add some results from a quiz so that when user gets each right answer it adds 1 to it but the code below never gives me the right answer the 'correctAns = correctAns+1'gives me all 5 at once, if I make the correctAns as local variable this will give me 1 for every right answer but it will NOT add up. Can any one please help.

```
 public class AdapterListView extends ArrayAdapter<Questions> {

    private int correctAns = 0;

     public AdapterListView(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Questions> questionsArrayList) {
        super(context, resource);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.setQuestionsArrayList(questionsArrayList);
        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    ....
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ...

        holder.editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                if (holder.editText.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                    int inputNum = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(holder.editText.getText().toString().trim()));

                    if (getAnswersList().get(position) != inputNum) {
                        holder.imgFalse.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.imgTrue.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    } else {

                        correctAns = correctAns+1;

                        holder.imgTrue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.imgFalse.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }                    
                }
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView questionTextView;
        EditText editText;
        ImageView imgTrue, imgFalse;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 0):

You should increase the value of variable `n`

**Replace**

```
setCorrectAns(++n);
```

**With this**

```
n=n+1;
```

Comment: I've tried all this in all sorts of different ways nothing seems to be working right.